# Openlayers 3 layer style issue

Tags: styles, icons, layer, openlayers-3

I need to create a layer with meteorological icons on it - about 100 of them. So. I define its source like this:

```
    mappingAPI.meteoIconLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
```

I add icons as features like this:

```
    for(stan in meteo.meteoData)
    {
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(meteo.meteoData[stan].lon), parseFloat(meteo.meteoData[stan].lat)], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857')),
            obj_id: meteo.meteoData[stan].obj_id,
        });

        mappingAPI.meteoIconLayerSource.addFeature(iconFeature);  
    }
```

Once I have the source, I create the layer like this:

```
    mappingAPI.meteoIconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: mappingAPI.meteoIconLayerSource,
        style: mappingAPI.getMeteoIconStyle            
    });
```

The style definition looks like this:

```
return [new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
    opacity: 0.7,
    src: "data/meteo/icon" + feature.get('obj_id') + ".png"
})];
```

When the src is defined as stated above (using feature's property pointing to unique number), icons on my map start blinking as the style procedure is call non-stop for all the features on the layer again and again. In case, I replace the definition with reference to one picture like this:

```
src: "data/meteo/icon3898.png",
```

or even like this:

```
src: "data/meteo/icon" + feature.get('dummy') + ".png",
```

where dummy is same for all features, everything is fine - the style procedure is called once for each features and that's it until map needs redrawing.

Please, could anybody help to with this issue? Or is there any other way, how to place icons on the map without putting src definition in the style?

Marek

Comment: You could try to set feature style inside your loop instead of layer.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/157222/50718) about caching style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like Openlayers has a problem with loading so many images and it periodically initiates reloading, when it's not finished in time (I am just guessing). In case I pre-load the images into image objects on my web page and I use img style property (instead of src), it works as expected. imgSize property has to be set as well, otherwise the icon is not displayed at all. The best way, how to do it is:

```
img: img,    
imgSize: [img.clientWidth,img.clientHeight]
```